# Convert to data into string similar to that of JSON

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, local-storage

Is there any better way to implement the below code

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return saveUserData('firstname','lastname');" method="post">
```

```js
function saveUserData() {
    createJSONString(arguments);
    return false;
}

function createJSONString(arguments) {
    var userDetails = "{";
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        userDetails += '"' + arguments[i] + '":' + '"'     +document.getElementById(arguments[i]).value + '",';
    }
    userDetails += '"' + arguments[i] + '":' + '"' + document.getElementById(arguments[i]).value + "}";
    alert(userDetails);
}
```

Basically the function saveUserData is called from the form submit button. So the idea is to passs parameters to the function and create a JSON like string so that i can store it in the localStorage variable of Chrome and Firefox. The Idea is not to fail OCP because in future if we add middle name the JavaScript code need not change only the HTML will change. 
Is there any better way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: I tried Indenting the code and pasting. Somehow everytime i format the code in my editor and paste it here the alignment goes haywire. How should i make sure the code is properly Indented?

Comment: Assuming my edit is approved, I formatted the code for you.  Generally, it's four spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: What happens when the field value happens to include a double quote? Why are you using this "JSON like" format (in a function called `createJSONString` and not `createJSONishString`) instead of just using JSON?

Comment: @DCoder because localStorage stores only JSON strings and not JSON.I mean to say even if we use JSON while storing it in localStorage we need to convert it using JSON.stringify e.g. localStorage.userDetails=JSON.stringify(userJSON);

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) or a wrapper library?

Comment: but it isnt it waste of effort. Converting string to JSON and again JSON to String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make JSON string using json.stringify method.
using json library, chrome and ff has build in this method.

http://json.org/

first you have to make javascript object for data like this.

```
var data = { 
    name : 'blu..',
    age  : 19
};

JSON.stringify(data);

// result is => "{"name":"blu..","age":19}"



function createJSONString(arguments) {
    var obj = {};     
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        obj[arguments[i]] = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).value;
    }

    return JSON.stringify(obj);
};
```

Comment: Thanks I just implemented the same after seeing DCoders comment.